# The Staff of Moses

Tags: midrash, rashi, moshe-rabbeinu

Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 40:

> Rabbi Levi said: That rod which was created in the twilight was delivered to the first man out of the garden of Eden. Adam delivered it to Enoch, and Enoch delivered it to Noah, and Noah [handed it on] to Shem. Shem passed it on to Abraham, Abraham [transmitted it] to Isaac, and Isaac [gave it over] to Jacob, and Jacob brought it down into Egypt and passed it on to his son Joseph, and when Joseph died and they pillaged his household goods, it was placed in the palace of Pharaoh. And Jethro was one of the magicians of Egypt, and he saw the rod and the letters which were upon it, and he desired in his heart (to have it), and he took it and brought it, and planted it in the midst of the garden of his house. No one was able to approach it any more. When Moses came to his house he went into the garden of Jethro's house, and saw the rod and read the letters which were upon it, and he put forth his hand and took it. Jethro watched || Moses, and said: This one in the future will redeem Israel from Egypt. Therefore he gave him Zipporah his daughter to wife, as it is said, "And Moses was content to dwell with the man; and he gave Moses Zipporah, his daughter" (Ex. 2:21).

Deuteronomy 4:32:

> "You have but to inquire about bygone ages that came before you, ever since God created humankind on earth, from one end of heaven to the other: has anything as grand as this ever happened, or has its like ever been known?"

Rashi also quotes a midrashic interpretation: This teaches that the height of Adam Harishon was from the earth until the heaven, which is the same distance as from one end of heaven etc...

And according to [Bava Batra 75a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.75a.12?lang=bi)- The height of Adam was 100 cubits (approx 150 feet).

Imagine a staff in the hand of a man who is 150 feet (the staff should also be very big to fit in his hand), and the same staff in the hand of a Man (Moshe)- who is 10 cubits/approx 15-20 feet tall (see [Talmud Berachot 54b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.54b.7?lang=bi)).
How was it possible? What was the height of staff? Is there any miracle hid in it?

Comment: I believe Aharon had his own completely separate stick so the title should reflect just Moshe...See here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52625/did-aharon-have-his-own-stick-like-moshe

Comment: Maybe it was only a piece of the original or it shrank miraculously?

Comment: Adams height is likely allegorical

Comment: Any sources for the height of the staff?